# C# kinect sensor chooser not in toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sdk, kinect, xbox360

In my toolbox I am not able to add a "KinectSensorChooser" to my MainWindow.
I have references to: Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.dll
I'm currently using a Kinect for xbox 360 and the kinect SDK 1.8

Other kinect tools are displayed in my toolbox, but this one seems to be missing.
Is there a way to add it ?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you have to link your project with Microsoft.Kinect extension and then use Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit as a namespace for your project. Using Kinect xbox360 or Kinect 1 for windows is the same.